# Setting Different Levels of constants for categorical variables in R

Tags: r, glm, predictive

Will anyone be able to explain how to set constants for different levels of categorical variables in r?

I have read the following: [How to set the Coefficient Value in Regression; R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234972/how-to-set-the-coefficient-value-in-regression-r) and it does a good job for explaining how to set a constant for the whole of a categorical variable.  I would like to know how to set one for each level.

As an example, let us look at the MTCARS dataset:

```
df <- as.data.frame(mtcars)

df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)
set.seed(1)
glm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + gear, data = df)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Call:  glm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + hp + gear, data = df)

Coefficients:

(Intercept)         cyl6         cyl8           hp         gear
     19.80268     -4.07000     -2.29798     -0.05541      2.79645  

Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  27 Residual

Null Deviance:      1126 

Residual Deviance: 219.5    AIC: 164.4
```

If I wanted to set cyl6 to -.34 and cyl8 to -1.4, and then rerun to see how it effects the other variables, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you can do

```
df$mpgCyl=df$mpg
df$mpgCyl[df$cyl==6]=df$mpgCyl[df$cyl==6]-0.34
df$mpgCyl[df$cyl==8]=df$mpgCyl[df$cyl==8]-1.4
model2=glm(mpgCyl ~ hp + gear, data = df)
> model2

Call:  glm(formula = mpgCyl ~ hp + gear, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           hp         gear  
   16.86483     -0.07146      3.53128
```

UPDATE withe comments:

`cyl` is a factor, therefore by default it contributes to `glm` as offset, not slope. Actually `cyl==4` is 'hidden' but existing in the `glm` as well. So in your first glm what the models says is:

```
1) for cyl==4: mpg=19.8-0.055*hp+2.79*gear
2) for cyl==6: mpg=(19.8-4.07)-0.055*hp+2.79*gear
3) for cyl==8: mpg=(19.8-2.29)-0.055*hp+2.79*gear
```

Maybe you can also check here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213710/level-of-factor-taken-as-intercept and here [Is there any way to fit a `glm()` so that all levels are included (i.e. no reference level)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347467/is-there-any-way-to-fit-a-glm-so-that-all-levels-are-included-i-e-no-refer)

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you.  Would you explain why it is `df$mpgCyl[df$cyl==6]=df$mpgCyl[df$cyl==6]-0.34` and not `df$mpgCyl[df$cyl==6]=df$mpgCyl[df$cyl==6]*0.34`?

Comment: I reply in updated answer as it requires some writing

Comment: Thank you.  I do understand the output of a factor as an offset compared to a slope (for continuous data).  Thank you for the update.  Now I see how your answer mathematically makes sense.